# How select a period of date from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I have a table in SQLite that has three fields (id, fromDate, toDate, uid). I want to select rows that has created in a specific dates. User select the period of time (from date/ to date). How I can query with ORMLite?

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite does not have a Date type([supported types](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html))
There is some dateTime [functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), i think that any of function will meet your requirement... The easier solution will be to convert you date to a timestamp and compare the timestamp.